# The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item

Tags: 2013

Suddenly our Crawl log Shows up: 48447 Errors.

Any suggestion will be appreciate:

The error showing :

The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item. ( SearchID = 9A5C59CC-1927-4496-B43A-9E72A125D644 )

[image]

Comment: check this if it applies to you...https://blog.kenaro.com/2012/04/20/error-in-crawl-log-the-sharepoint-item-being-crawled-returned-an-error-when-attempting-to-download-the-item/

Comment: Waqas, the blog link solved my problem with above error. Thanks. Also do you think we should change to IE11 agent string for SP2016?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the size of these document files?

In Search Service Application is link to the Farm Search Administration : http://APPserver:PORT/searchfarmdashboard.aspx where you can set TIme-out (seconds) for downloading and indexing documents.

Try this and provide us more information about the documents.